# Why does this probability equivalence of events hold?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, markov-chains

$P(X_0 = j, X_m \ne j, 1 \le m \le n-1) = P(X_m \ne j, 1 \le m \le n-1) - P(X_m \ne j, 0 \le m \le n-1) $

Where

$\{X_n\}$ is an irreducible Markov Chain with a finite state space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basic probability; it has nothing to do with Markov chains.
Define $A=(X_0=j)$ and $B=\cap_{m=1}^{n-1}(X_m\neq j)$. Then your equation
simply says 
$$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(B)-\mathbb{P}(\bar A\cap B).$$
This is true because $B$ is the disjoint union of $A\cap B$ and $\bar A\cap B$,
where I'm using $\bar A$ to denote the complement of $A$.